# Why the sum of the array elements always end up printing the same value?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{int array1[10],i=0,sum=0;

while(i<10)
{scanf("%d",&array1[i]);
i=i+1;
}
while(i<10)
{sum=sum+array1[i];i=i+1;
}

printf("sum =%d",sum);
   return 0;
}
```

The code compiles fine but while running it does not produce any result, it always prints 0.

Comment: `DO SEND CORRECTED CODE FOR ME TO CHECK IT ON MY COMPILE`...emm...why's that? Who's payin'?

Comment: You are not resetting i to 0 after taking the input into your array.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. It comes real handy while debugging small (even medium-to-big size) programs. It would have taken less time to find out the error if you had actually used a debugger than posting the question here.,

Comment: `#include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h> int main() {int array1[10],i=0,sum=0; while(i<10) {scanf("%d",&array1[i]); sum=sum+array1[i]; i=i+1; } printf("sum =%d",sum); return 0; }` Lol you need to check these ur self while learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the second loop. Check the value of `i` while entering the `while` loop body and thereafter.

> You need to reset the value of `i`. Otherwise, the second loop does not execute. After the execution of the first loop, `i` hold a value of `10` and unless changed, the second `while` loop condition evaluates to false, thus the loop body does not execute, leaving `sum` to it's initialized value.

That said,

- `int main()` should better be `int main(void)` for a hosted environment.
- Always check the return value of `scanf()` for success before using the scanned value.

Comment: but I cannot write that int i =0 after first loop

Comment: @AniketMalik why's that?

Comment: @AniketMalik Whoops, it's not `int i =0;`, it's `i =0;`, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize i=0 after first loop. At the end of first loop, the value of i is 10 so it will not enter second loop. Thus prints 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int array1[10],i=0,sum=0;

    while(i<10)
    {
        scanf("%d",&array1[i]);
        i=i+1;
    }

    i=0;          // Notice this line
    while(i<10)
    {
        sum=sum+array1[i];i=i+1;
    }

    printf("sum =%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable i is not initialized to 0 in the second loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{int array1[10],i=0,sum=0;

while(i<10)
{scanf("%d",&array1[i]);
i=i+1;
}
/*After the execution of 1st while loop i has 10 in it, that needs to be set to 0 for next loop execution, for this use case.

 If it is not mandatory to use while loop, try with **for loop**, it is far simple for this use case. */

for( i=0; i<10; i++) //while( i<10)
{sum=sum+array1[i];//i=i+1;
}

printf("sum =%d",sum);
   return 0;
}
```

Else go with a single loop, which makes your code more simple

```
int main()
{int array1[10],i,sum=0;

for( i=0; i<10; i++){
   scanf("%d",&array1[i]);
   sum=sum+array1[i];
}

printf("sum =%d",sum);
   return 0;
}
```